# ¿Como ejecutar bien esta consulta en Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-10g

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE, DEPTNO, ROWNUM AS rn
FROM (SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE, DEPTNO FROM EMP ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC) 
WHERE rn < 3
```

pero el error es:

> ORA-00904: "RN": identificador no válido
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error en la línea: 34, columna: 7

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer funcionar de esa u otra forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no uso Oracle, pero creo que tengo una idea.
Prueba ha cambiar el `where rn` por `where rownum`, asi:

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE, DEPTNO, ROWNUM AS rn
FROM (SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE, DEPTNO FROM EMP ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC) 
WHERE ROWNUM < 3
```

Si no te funciona, puedes probar esta otra solución, que consiste en envolver toda la consulta en otra, asi:

```
Select EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE, DEPTNO, rn from 
(
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE, DEPTNO, ROWNUM AS rn
FROM (SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE, DEPTNO FROM EMP ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC) 
)
WHERE rn < 3
```

Comment: Ambas opciones funcionarán, pero obviamente, la primera es preferible.